# Tricky array arithmetics inside a __global__ kernel (CUDA samples)

Tags: cuda

I have a question about code from CUDA sample "CUDA Separable Convolution" . In order to make row-convolution, this code first loads data in shared memory. Using pointer arithmetics, each thread moves the input pointers into their own position, and after that writes some piece of global memory into shared memory. Here is the piece of code that confuses me:

```
__global__ void convolutionRowsKernel(
    float *d_Dst,
    float *d_Src,
    int imageW,
    int imageH,
    int pitch
    )
{
    __shared__ float s_Data[ROWS_BLOCKDIM_Y][(ROWS_RESULT_STEPS + 2 *     ROWS_HALO_STEPS) * ROWS_BLOCKDIM_X];

    //Offset to the left halo edge
    const int baseX = (blockIdx.x * ROWS_RESULT_STEPS - ROWS_HALO_STEPS) * ROWS_BLOCKDIM_X + threadIdx.x;
    const int baseY = blockIdx.y * ROWS_BLOCKDIM_Y + threadIdx.y;

    d_Src += baseY * pitch + baseX;
    d_Dst += baseY * pitch + baseX;

    //Load main data
#pragma unroll

    for (int i = ROWS_HALO_STEPS; i < ROWS_HALO_STEPS + ROWS_RESULT_STEPS; i++)
    {
        s_Data[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x + i * ROWS_BLOCKDIM_X] = d_Src[i * ROWS_BLOCKDIM_X];
    }
...
```

As far as I understand this code, each thread will calculate their own values of `baseX` and `baseY`, and after that **all** active threads will start to increase pointers `d_Src` and `d_Dst` **simultaneously**.

So, according to my knowledge, this would be correct, if arrays `d_Src` and `d_Dst` were in local memory (e.g. each thread would have there own copy of this arrays). But this arrays are in global device memory! So what will happen, all active threads will increase the pointers, and the result will be incorrect. Can one explain me, why this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because every thread has its own copy of the pointer.

```
void foo(float* bar){
    bar++;
}

float* test = 0;
foo(test);
cout<<test<<endl; //will print 0
```

Comment: So, is that true, that any input pointer is automatically put into local memory, e.g. each thread has its own copy of it, however the data pointer points to is in global device memory, as it was before kernel call?

Comment: Yes the data (where the pointers point to) is still in global memory. Your problem has actually nothing to do with cuda or global memory, it's just how pointers work in c.